# What access is required for azure Service principle to list down the user information from AAD

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

What access is required for azure Service principle to list down the user information from AAD, Directory Read, group read, user read graph api permissions were given to the Service principal.

When using the Az AD user list command in azure CLI it is still showing error:

> Insufficient privileges.

What other access is required for service principal to list down the users?

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application and added **`User.Read.All`** API permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

Now, I ran below below **CLI command** to connect with Azure via service principal:

```
az login --service-principal -u <appID> -p <clientsecret> --tenant <tenantID> --allow-no-subscriptions
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below CLI command, I got the **response** with list of users successfully like below:

```
az ad user list
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to add **`User.Read.All`** Application permission to the service principal and grant **admin consent** to it.