# How to get all users from AAD from an Azure Function by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

How to get all users from AAD from an Azure Function by PowerShell? I googled around and try some tutorials, but they are al failed. I hope someone has some solution which works.

Comment: What did you try before? You need to use system assigned or user assigned principal. Use this to login: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316128/what-access-is-required-for-azure-service-principle-to-list-down-the-user-inform | after it you can easily get users with `az ad user list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure that your Azure Function has the necessary permissions to read user information from AAD. this is imp

and include the required modules in your PowerShell script:

```html
# This assumes you have the AzureAD module installed
Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -AllowPrerelease -MinimumVersion 7.0.0-preview

Import-Module Az
```

Now get all the users you need

```html
# Authenticate to Azure AD
$tenantId = "<YourTenantId>"
$clientId = "<YourClientId>"
$clientSecret = "<YourClientSecret>"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientId, $secpasswd)

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -ApplicationId $clientId -Credential $credential

# Get all users
$users = Get-AzADUser -All $true

# Output user information
$users | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, ObjectId
```